# CSS is not updating in Processwire

Tags: css, sass, mamp, koala, processwire

This is a question specific to the Processwire CMS but actually I'm not sure where the problem might exactly be coming from

I've just started my first Processwire project and have set the back end to my liking. Upon starting the front end of my site I encountered a very strange problem: The CSS file is not updating.
I started off and soon the problem occured. I then simply copied the contents of main.css to a new main2.css file, changed the code in the template file, and it worked again. Thinking it was a one time thing I continued, but it didn't take long for the problem to happen again.
Locally the files are changed and the html code of my project is updating normally, but when I inspect the page, the changes in the CSS file are nowhere to be seen.

I'm using MAMP to create the local server and Koala to compile my SASS Code.  I'm new to processwire and am still pretty early in my web developer career, nontheless I'm very confused about what's happening, since the problem is only partially occuring in the CSS file and not in the HTML (or PHP) file.

Does anyone have an idea as to what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: welcome to the processwire world..good choice ;) some questions: maybe browser caching? what installation profile do you use? have you changed anything in your .htaccess? how do you reference the css (have you changed anything)? sass compiler works always correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a problem with caching. Please read https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html for example, to understand what browser caching is and what task it accomplishes.

On this page under "Common caching issue" you find your problem.

If you are using Chrome, open the Dev Tools (F12) and under the Network tab check "Disable cache".

In Firefox open the Firefox Toolbox (also F12) and under Settings > Advanced settings check "Disable HTTP-Cache if Toolbox is open" (I translated this from a german Firefox).

After that make changes in your CSS file and reload the page. If your changes appear then you know you stumbled into one of the pitfalls of browser-caching.

There are many strategies to deal with this "problem". Take a look at https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/ for some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a bit of php code in my `_init.php` to add version number to css file name.

> Most browsers these days will see a URL with a different query string as a different file and download a fresh copy. Most CDN's even support and recommend this. More here: [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/)

And here is PHP:

```
// Set path and url
$assets_path = $config->paths->templates . "your-folder/";
$assets_url = $config->urls->templates . "your-folder/";
$file_css = "app.css";

// Generate css version addon
// Check if file exists and get date of last change
if (file_exists($assets_path . $file_css)) {
  $css_version_addon = "?v" . date("His", filemtime($assets_path . 
  $file_css)); // Time of last change 23h 59m 59s in format 235959
} else {
  $css_version_addon = "?somethingWentWrong";
}

// Full url with css file and version addon
$css_with_version = $assets_url . $file_css . $css_version_addon;
```

You can output it in your template

```
// In your template file
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $css_with_version; ?>" />
// This will output to something like this
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/templates/your-folder/app.css?v101525" />
```

I am using this in all of my ProcessWire templates. As @jmartsch mentioned, there are many strategies, but this one suits me best.
It doesn't matter how you generate your file (I am using scss with gulp for generating css). Script just check if file was modified and output time of change.